# How to 'connect' elements with interfaces that are subsets of each other?

Tags: modelica

We are developing a simple library to concurrently model hydrologic processes and open channel flow.

For open channel flow elements (1-D shallow water equations, weirs, etc.) we use a connector with discharge (Q) as flow variable and water level (H) as across variable. In hydrologic applications, on the other hand, popular choices for routing schema's only involve Q as variable. In such models flow is not driven by a potential (H) difference, but more empirically specified.

Whe would like to set up the package in such a way that (Q,H)-elements can be connected to Q-only elements. In addition, if possible, one type of element should be easily interchangeable for the other type of element.

As an example, below is a simple set-up ("Integrated") with a reservoir ("Storage"), one routing element ("PassFlow") and a source ("Discharge"). The reservoir needs to expose both Q and H, so that it can interact with (Q-H) open channel flow elements (not present in this example). Here, it is connected to an element that is, in principle, Q-only. It still uses a (Q,H)-connector to allow the connection. There is, however, no equation for the water level. This means we need to add a dummy equation to the Integrated model to close the system, which is clearly undesirable.

```
within Deltares;

package Test
  connector FlowPort
    flow Real Q;
    Real H;
  end FlowPort;

  model Discharge
    Real Q;
    FlowPort port;
  equation
    port.Q + Q = 0;
  end Discharge;

  model Storage
    FlowPort port;
  equation
    der(port.H) = port.Q;
  end Storage;

  model PassFlow "Inflow is outflow, level is untouched"
    FlowPort upstream;
    FlowPort downstream;
  equation
    upstream.Q + downstream.Q = 0;
  end PassFlow;

  model Integrated
    Deltares.Test.Discharge discharge;
    Deltares.Test.PassFlow passflow;
    Deltares.Test.Storage storage;
  equation
    connect(discharge.port, passflow.upstream);
    connect(passflow.downstream, storage.port);
    discharge.Q = 10;
    passflow.upstream.H = -1;
    //I want to avoid this equation
  end Integrated;
end Test;
```

Would it be possible to define a single connector for both types of elements, without the need for adding dummy equations? We've tried using an expandable connector, but without success so far. Could expandable connectors accommodate this idea?